# is this a true way to find unite eigenvectors for this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2\\0&2&1\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix}$$
IS:

> $V_1=[1, 0, 0]^T$, $V_2=[1,1,0]^T$, $V_3=[\frac32,1,1]^T$

To find  unit eigenvectors I had found the magnitude of each vector(by adding them squared under a square root) and then divide each eigenvector by that magnitude

so the unite eigenvector for V2 would be :
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\0  \end{bmatrix}

is that right ?

Comment: That is how I would do it.

Comment: That's *the* way to normalize a vector.

Answer (score 1):

An Eigenvector multiplied by a scalar remains an Eigenvector:

$$M(a\vec v)=a(M\vec v)=a\lambda\vec v=\lambda(a\vec v).$$

So if you want a unit Eigenvector,

$$\|a\vec v\|=|a|\|\vec v\|=1$$ has the two solutions $$a=\pm\frac1{\|\vec v\|}.$$